# Locker Succulents

Tags: plant-care, succulents, grow-lamp

So my friend and I want to grow succulents in our locker. They will have no natural light but were thinking of getting them some form of battery powered grow lights and a fan to keep air circulation. With no natural light does anyone have suggestions of what type of Grow light kind of thing we should get? As I’m sure you were wondering her plant is named baby and mine are named spiky Mikey and Lina

Answer (score 1):

Mikey and Lina.
Yes, you can grow a plant, even a succulent with just artificial light, as long as you have have the correct heat, meaning something around 20-25°c (70-80°f)  A little higher or lower is fine.  The temperature can drop at night, but the temperatures should stay above 10°c (50°f), you have the air circulation, and water.  With all those components you can grow succulents in a locker.
This is to assume you can create the battery power to keep a grow light with the right type of light going for 16-20 hours each day.  You might be able to get away with less time.  I would look for an LED Full-Spectrum white light that is minimum 100W equivalent.  This is minimum.  If you want the plant to really grow and thrive I would start with a 300W, maybe 200W.  Once you go over 100W most grow lights have fans to keep the lights from getting too hot and burn out.   This fan is usually what draws the most power.  You might be able to find a fanless light strong enough, but the heat it makes needs to go somewhere.  If you were in a grow tent with lots of extra room the temperature would not get too high, but a closed locker might.   Is the front mesh like a locker room or completely sealed with a couple vents on top.
I think you need to try to buy two 100W LED lights.  That way you can avoid buying one with a fan.  That way you can see what the heat is going to be like without spending a fortune on a project that may not work, but I think it can.
With the air circulation you mentioned, you may be able to keep it cool enough.   You can probably get some kind of rechargeable battery.  To have the battery power to keep a light that will keep a plant happy will be a high cost  for you.    You also need to figure out how to turn an AC light to operate on DC batteries, which is doable.
The whole project is doable.  But, you have a lot of hurdles to cross first.  You will probably kill the first plant while you are test, maybe the the first two plants, but you will not figure out what you are missing unless you have some failures.  The best gardeners kill plants.  That's how they learn.